# Trailing whitespace in Safari when floating divs?

Tags: css, safari

when I float left say 4 divs, all with a width of 25%, I get a bit of space within the container in Safari and also on mobile. I can't quite work out why as the issue isn't there is fellow webkit browser Chrome.

The container is 100%, so the divs should just fill it? Here is a screenshot of a test image to demonstrate:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8ThO.png

So the container has a red background, and the 4 divs have width of 25% and are floated left. They have a white border (with border-box attributed). As you can see there is trailing whitespace! Again, this is only in Safari and on mobile devices.

Here is the (s)css:-

```
.test-area {
width:50%;
margin:0 auto;
float:left;
background:red;
font-size:80%;

.test-box {
width:25%;
padding-bottom:33.33%;
background:black;
float:left;
border:1px solid white;

}
}
```

Here is the html:-

```
<div class="test-area">
<div class="test-box"></div>
<div class="test-box"></div>
<div class="test-box"></div>
<div class="test-box"></div>
<div class="test-box"></div>
<div class="test-box"></div>

</div><!--end test-area-->
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: please post the minimal css and markup in a fiddle in order to reproduce the issue. By border-box do you mean `box-sizing`?

Comment: Sounds like a pixel rounding / sub-pixel issue  in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what you are seeing in Safari (perhaps you are using an old version). Anyhow, by default, border is added to the overall width, so it's not safe to set your divs to width: 25% and hope that they will fit 4 per row—unless you change your box sizing to include the borders (and padding) with something like this:

```
*, *:before, *:after {-moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}
```

Comment: Yep I'm using box-sizing, otherwise it would break the container rather than cause there to be a gap. I found this article - http://maxlapides.com/fixing-subpixel-layout-rendering-in-safari/ that seems to be the issue I'm having. If you try resizing your browser, you may see the issue.